# scp fails in one direction

Tags: remote-access, file-transfer, scp

I've been doing some work on one of our school's servers (as a student), and I've been having some trouble scp-ing files in and out. Trying to push/pull a file from the server while logged in on my local machine

```
user@localHost$ scp <user>@<schoolServ>:<file> .
```

doesn't work and causes the terminal to hang indefinitely. However, I have no problems ssh-ing to the remote machine, and trying the transfer from the other direction

```
user@schoolServ$ scp <file> <user>@<localHost>:~/.
```

works fine. I've tried three different machines (OS X & Linux) to no effect. Any ideas what might cause this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scp might have a verbose option, try that and see what it shows. I had a similar issue once and turned out that some commands in .profile or .bashrc on the target machine were writing out a blank line with non printing chars. That caused an issue with the ssl handshake

Comment: Aha! Bingo! Somehow a .rc file got configured to initialize everything for csh, then threw it all away to start up bash which messed everything up. Found & nuked the offending line, and everything works fantastically now. Thanks!